# Svelte app not getting returning json from PHP

Tags: php, api, svelte

I'm very new to Svelte and quite new to PHP.
I need a little help to login to a maria database from a Svelte using PHP as backend.
With the code written till now seems that logins works but I have a problem with the returning json from PHP to Svelte. In browser's console I got the following message:

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at
> line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

A bit of code; this is login.php:

```php
...
// Try and connect using the info above.
$con = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);
if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
    // If there is an error with the connection, stop the script and display the error.
    exit('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
// Now we check if the data from the login form was submitted, isset() will check if the data exists.
if ( !isset($data->username, $data->password) ) {
    // Could not get the data that should have been sent.
    exit('Please fill both the username and password fields!');
}

// Prepare our SQL, preparing the SQL statement will prevent SQL injection.
if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id, password FROM accounts WHERE username = ?')) {
    // Bind parameters (s = string, i = int, b = blob, etc), in our case the username is a string so we use "s"
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $data->username);
    $stmt->execute();
    // Store the result so we can check if the account exists in the database.
    $stmt->store_result();

    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $password);
        $stmt->fetch();
        // Account exists, now we verify the password.
        // Note: remember to use password_hash in your registration file to store the hashed passwords.
        if (password_verify($data->password, $password)) {
            // Verification success! User has logged-in!
            // Create sessions, so we know the user is logged in, they basically act like cookies but remember the data on the server.
            session_regenerate_id();
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
            $_SESSION['name'] = $data->username;
            $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
            echo 'Welcome ' . $_SESSION['name'] . '!';
            $response = array("success" => true);
        } else {
            // Incorrect password
            echo 'Incorrect username and/or password!';
            $response = array("success" => false, "message" => "Incorrect username and/or password");
        }
    } else {
        // Incorrect username
        echo 'Incorrect username and/or password!';
        $response = array("success" => false, "message" => "Incorrect username and/or password");
    }
    error_log(print_r(json_encode($response), TRUE)); // seems ok: got "{"success":true}" in console
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
    $stmt->close();
}
```

This is the page.svelte:

```html
<script>
  import { Button } from 'daisyui';

  let username = '';
  let password = '';
  let error = '';

  const handleLogin = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost/app/login.php', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: JSON.stringify({ username, password })
    });

    const json = await response.json();
    console.log(json)
    if (json.success) {
      // Login successful, redirect to main page
      window.location.href = 'main.html';
    } else {
      // Login failed, display error message
      error = json.message;
    }
  }
</script>

<div class="container mx-auto max-w-sm">
  <h1 class="text-2xl font-bold mb-4">Login</h1>

  {#if error}
    <div class="bg-red-200 text-red-700 px-4 py-2 mb-4 rounded-md">{error}</div>
  {/if}

  <form on:submit|preventDefault={handleLogin}>
    <div class="mb-4">
      <label class="block text-gray-700 font-bold mb-2" for="username">Username</label>
      <input class="form-input rounded-md shadow-sm w-full" type="text" id="username" bind:value={username} required />
    </div>
    <div class="mb-4">
      <label class="block text-gray-700 font-bold mb-2" for="password">Password</label>
      <input class="form-input rounded-md shadow-sm w-full" type="password" id="password" bind:value={password} required />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Credentials are correctly passed to php and login seems to work (in the web serverlog I can read {"success":true}; but Svelte seems not receiving the json. Moreover, it is as all the code after "response = await fetch" is not executed.

Any clues?

A side question? Should I continue using php or should I think about adopting another backend, like node.js?

Thanks

Comment: You're echoing random strings as well as the json encoded response, which will throw off the response that svelte is expecting

Comment: I commented all echo lines except the json encoded response and now it works. Thanks

Comment: When debugging json parsing errors, it's helpful to read the fetch text() stream (response.text() in your code, instead of response.json()) first, which can then be inspected/logged. Then JSON.parse that as a separate step.